# Are there Radio Buttons Group and Dropdownlists in Orchard Dynamic Forms?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I'm developing a form using Orchard Dynamic Forms module. There is no option for a Radio Button Group controls and a dropdownlist to be used on form.

I have used Text fields, single radio buttons successfully.

How to use Radio button groups and dropdownlists in orchard Dynamic Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Radio button Groups and Dropdownlists are available in `Orchard.Dynamic Forms`. Such elements are actually treated as Enumerations.

When creating a form, Under `Form` elements there is an `Enumeration` element as seen below.
[image]
Drag it to your Form , when the Edit Window open up. As seen below, from the `Input Type` option you can create a dropdown or a radio button list.
[image]

If you want to learn more, check the `.CSHTML` files at location: `Orchard.DynamicForms -> Views -> Elements` and the code at location:`Orchard.DynamicForms -> Elements`

Comment: Thank you specially for pointing me to Code and html files. There is a lot more information there to make myself familiar with Dynamic Forms working.